# How can I access User Rights Assignment in Windows XP Home Edition?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy

I have a computer running Windows XP Home Edition SP3.  To run a script I've developed that automates printer installations, I need to make some changes to the user group so that limited users can run [Microsoft's DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272).

Here's the option I'm asking about from Windows XP Pro: 
gpedit.msc isn't available and if you side-install it there's no option to change security settings, it's just missing.

[image: User Rights Assignment from XP Pro]
I want to give normal users the right to Load and unload device drivers, among other things.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do it using the console like you've pictured on Windows XP Home Edition.  As you've found out, even after [installing Group Policy Editor](http://www.trishtech.com/winxp/install_group_policy_editor_in_windows_xp_home_edition.php), if it's run on Windows XP Home Edition, `Windows Settings` will only have `Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)` unlike the picture shown.

To make these changes (and also to apply rights to groups you've created in XP Home) you need [NTRIGHTS.EXE](http://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html) from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657).

This will allow you to Edit user account and group Privileges from an administrator 
account Command Shell:

The same options presented in

XP Home
[image: Command prompt example]

XP Pro
[image: Windows XP Pro example]

Just run `ntrights /?` to get the whole list of available options.